# MySQL inner join too long

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, inner-join

My schema is as follow :

Table A
id
fieldA_1
fieldA_2
fieldA_3
fieldA_4

Table B
id
fieldB_1
fieldB_2
fieldB_3
fieldB_4

The specificity is that Table A has ~ 100 000 entries and table B has ~5 000 000 entries.
Both table have the same number of distinct id (100 000).
There are 5 000 000 distinct combination  for (id, fieldB_2) in table B.

I want to do a query that select field from both table and return 100 000 result maximum (one per ID, or less depending of the filter, that could be any field of the table A or B except fieldB_2).

As there are several raw for each id of the table B, I don't care of which value is return but it should be fast (I mean for example for fieldB_3 I want any of the field3 value associated to a device).
The only exception is for field fieldB_1 for which I want the list of all the existing values for each id in the result. If performance are bad to have the list I can do a second request later only for this point so in my research I haven't try to get this list yet.

What I have tried is :

```
select distinct id,fieldB_1,fieldB_2,fieldB_3,fieldB_4
    from B
    where id IN (SELECT id from A where fieldA_1 >0);
```

And this :

```
select distinct B.id,fieldB_1,fieldB_2,fieldB_3,fieldB_4, fieldA_2,fieldA_3,fieldA_4 from B
INNER JOIN (SELECT id from A where fieldA_1 >0) ON A.id = B.id;
```

The query is taking more than 5 sec (both of them). Without the distinct the query is only ~10% faster.

I have 3 index :

- one on id (table A)
- one on id (table B)
- one on fieldA_1 (table A)

Is there a way to do this query faster ? (without the aggregation list for fieldB_1 at list ? )

Comment: `IN (SELECT ...)` Big `IN` clauses are usually a bad idea.  This is not a join, it is a sub select and at *best* they will have the performance of an equivalent join.

Comment: I will add the join, I have same performance

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Ty for the distinct precision, also I have tested without it, it's ~10% faster (so I don't think the problem is from there)

Comment: 100k rows _and_ fast?  No. You can't have both.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; it will be so much more precise.

Comment: `IN (SELECT ...)` is often slow.  Try to us a `JOIN` instead.